# how to execute only portion of shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible to run only portions of a shell script? For example, I just want to execute certain lines, but when I try copy and pasting, not all of my code gets entered in.

Is there a command to run a portion of a script?

Comment: How about `sed -n '10,12p; 13q' script.sh | bash`

Comment: What editor do you use? What do you mean by "not all of my code gets entered in"?

Comment: Hi choroba, I'm using notepad++, when I copy and paste large portions of code, only a subset of it gets copied into my promt.

Comment: Copy it to a file and run the file, instead of copying to the prompt directly.

Answer (score 2):

I usually structure my scripts as a set of functions, and then the main body has this entry:

```
if [ -z $sourceMe ]; then
    call_func1
    call_func2
    ...
fi
```

So then, if I need to run just one of the functions in the script, I can invoke it from an interactive shell to do that:

```
$    sourceMe=1 source ./myscript.sh ; call_func1
```

This makes it easy to test (or retest) specific functions in the script, or reuse their logic in other scripts without refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

you can temporarily deactivate part of a script by adding a "#" at the beginning of each "not-to-be-runned" script line.

With vim, you can do that by using the visual selection (type "v" and move the cursor with arrows) ; then type ":" and "s/^/#/" ; and save with ":w" + enter.
Then, when you launch the script, only the rest of it will work.

Once you're finished, you can re-activate your "not-to-be-runned" section by selecting it and replacing yours "#" at the beginning of the lines by typing ":" and then "s/^#//" ; and save with ":w" + enter.